# Time complexity n^k, k is a numeric variable, is this pseudo-polynomial?

Tags: algorithm

If the algorithm's time complexity is n^k

n is the number of element and k is a numeric variable which upper bound is 720 and lower bound is 1, and k is independent of n

Can O(n^k) be called pseudo-polynomial?

If not, do you think that this is better than O(2^n)?

---

Edited:

If k does not have upper bound, can O(n^k) be called pseudo-polynomial?

And if not, do you think that this is better than O(2^n)?

Comment: Since k has an upperbound of 720, that means worst case it is *O(n^720)*, which is still polynomial (although perhaps not in a "practical" sense). So this is polynomial

Comment: Why pseudo? There is an upper bound on k so it is polynomial. And this is still much better than 2^n if n is large enough.

Comment: not only O(n^720) is polynomial but is better then O(2^n) of course.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts But that doesn't matter if we are talking in terms of O-complexity as we known nothing about the multiplicative constants used...

Comment: oh! It seems that I ask a stupid question. So, if the knapsack problem's capacity has an upper bound, we can call that O(nK) is polynomial, right?

Comment: well, if k does not have upper bound, can O(n^k) be called pseudo-polynomial?

Comment: @chenyuxian: if it does not have an upper bound, then it can be *O(n^n)*, which grows faster than *O(2^n)*, hence in that case, it is worse than exponential. Then it depends on how k "behaves".

Comment: @chenyuxian: but the term "pseudopolynomial" depends more on the "type of input". In fact in a strict sense, it is still exponetial, but *poynomial* in the *numerical* value it represents with that much bits.

Comment: 2^n > n^720 for n >= 9516 so eventually the latter is better, though the number of operations is intractable long before n.

Comment: Back of envelope it would take the world's fastest supercomputer about 10^2830 lifetimes of the universe to reach the breakeven point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *k* has an upper bound of *720*, that means worst case, the algorithm scales with *O(n<sup>720</sup>)*, so that means it is *polynomial*.

*Asymptotically* this is better than *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*, so that means that eventually, for a large enough *n* the *O(n<sup>720</sup>)* algorithm will outperform the *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* algorithm. But it depends on a lot of factors if for *practical* input this is better.

For example, if it exactly takes *n<sup>720</sup>* step for the first algorithm, and *2<sup>n</sup>* for the second (big oh does *not* implies this), then the first *n* for which this will hold is *n=9'516*. This means that the first algorithm will perform *3.070×10<sup>2865</sup>* steps, whereas the second algorithm will take *3.994×10<sup>2865</sup>* steps. If these are simple CPU instructions, with todays technology this is is several orders of magnitudes too large to be feasible.

If for example *n* is typically small, and the "constant factor" of an exponential algorithm is lower, then it can - in practice - sometimes be better to use an *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* algorithm. But as said, this really depends on the specifics of the algorithm and the input.

Comment: How about if k does not have upper bound?

Comment: @chenyuxian: if it does not have an upper bound, then it can be *O(n^n)*, which grows faster than *O(2^n)*, hence in that case, it is worse than exponential.